# 1980s Kids book series about a sports star who played a game similar to American football and joins a war against aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I'm looking to track down a series of short books I read in the late 1980s in the UK. I think they were between 8-12 books quite short (100 pages at most) with a different bold colour for each cover.

The plot was set in the future and was about a sports star (not Flash Gordon) who played a game similar to American football, seem to remember they had spikes on their body armour. As the series goes on he becomes involved in a war against aliens and towards the end of the series his kids also join the fight.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 0):

Might it be the *[Galactic Football League](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38390971-galactic-football-league-bundle)* series by Scott Sigler?

> Set in a lethal pro football league 700 years in the future, the Galactic Football League is a story that combines the intense gridiron action of "Any Given Sunday" with the space opera style of "Star Wars" and the criminal underworld of "The Godfather." Aliens and humans alike play positions based on physiology, creating receivers that jump 25 feet into the air, linemen that bench-press 1,200 pounds, and linebackers that literally want to eat you. Organized crime runs every franchise, games are fixed and rival players are assassinated.
>
> Follow the story of Quentin Barnes, a 19-year-old quarterback prodigy that has been raised all his life to hate, and kill, those aliens. Quentin must deal with his racism and learn to lead, or he'll wind up just another stat in the column marked "killed on the field."

There are only six books so far, but the author has apparently written other books and short stories in the same setting.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48388/books-in-the-near-future-with-an-american-football-type-game-superhuman-players/197044#197044 has it as an unaccepted answer.